# jQuery Grab id's before form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, onsubmit

I have a page with a form where I need to grab all the ID attributes of the A links in a certain div, and attach those to the form in a hidden form field before submission. How might I do this?

i.e

```
<form action="/myaction" id="myForm">
<div id="recipients">
<a id="1">recipient one</a>
<a id="2">recipient two</a>
<a id="3">recipient three</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sendMail">Send</a>
</form>

<script>
//Capture form before sending
$("#sendMail").click( function() {
//Do something here to loop over the a tags in the recipients div, 
//and add as a list to a new hidden form field        
$('#myForm').trigger('submit');
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW: IDs **must not** start with a digit, but with a letter. [See W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

Comment: @Thorsten - Unless you use the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype

Comment: @James jQuery has issues using IDs beginning with numbers in it's selectors - at least it did up to 1.7, not sure if this has been fixed now HTML5 allows it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I've never heard about any issues around that... here's a fiddle using jQuery 1.2.6: http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/15/

Comment: Hmm interesting. I know I've encountered the problem in the past - although it was perhaps a plugin which had the issue. I apologies to the gods of jQuery for besmirching its' good name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started:

```
$("#sendMail").click(function() {
    var recipients = "";
    $("#recipients a").each(function() {
        recpients += this.id + ",";
    });
    $("#someHiddenField").val(recipients);
    $("#myForm").trigger("submit");
});
```

You can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the set of `a` elements, build up a string containing the `id` values, and use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value of a hidden input element to that string. In the example above you will get a comma-separated string, with a trailing comma. I don't know exactly what you're looking for, so you may want to change that.

Comment: This doesn't create a new hidden field and assumes the fields are already in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The code in my answer is just meant as a starting point really. I doubt the OP wants a trailing comma in the hidden input value, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Great, this does what I need it to do! Cheers

Comment: I suppose it depends what he's trying to achieve. Maybe your solution is better for a big series of numbers or small text, instead of filling the DOM with a bunch of small input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to create the new hidden fields.

So to loop round all `a` tags in recipients and append a new hidden field:

```
$("#recipients a").each(function() {
    $("#myform").append('<input type="hidden" name="'+this.id+'" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />')
});
```

*Note:* you didn't say what you want the name and value of the hidden fields to be, so I guessed at using `this.id` for the name and [$(this).text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

var Anchors = $("body").find("a")
var str = "";
    alert(Anchors.length);

    $(Anchors).each(function(){
        if(str !== ""){
            str+=",";   
        }

        str+=$(this).attr("id");
    })

 $("sometextfieldid").val(str);
```